# PHPMailer sending e-mail without form data

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a e-mail with a contact form but it`s not showing the data.
I've tried some answers here but can't get it to work.

My code:

```
<form class="form form-container method="post" action="assets/send_form_email.php">
    <div class="left">
      <input name="f_name" type="text" id="f_name" placeholder="Nome*" required />  
      <input name="f_email" type="email" id="f_email" placeholder="Email*" required />  
      <input name="f_phone" type="text" id="f_phone" required="required" maxlength="15"  placeholder="Telefone*" />  
      <textarea name="f_msg" id="f_msg" placeholder="Mensagem" rows="6"></textarea>  
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      <input name="f_cnpj" type="text" id="f_cnpj" placeholder="CNPJ" style="font-weight: 700;" required />  
      <input name="f_sector" type="text" id="f_sector" placeholder="Setor da empresa" style="font-weight: 700;" required />  
      <input name="f_faturamento" type="text" id="f_faturamento" placeholder="Faturamento médio" style="font-weight: 700;" required /> 
      <input name="f_valorMedio" type="text" id="f_valorMedio" placeholder="Valor médio de duplicatas" style="font-weight: 700;" required /> 
      <button type="submit" class="botaoContato">Enviar</button>
    </div>  
  </form>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['f_name'];
$email = $_POST['f_email'];
$telefone = $_POST['f_phone'];
$cnpj = $_POST['f_cnpj'];
$setor = $_POST["f_sector"];
$faturamento = $_POST['f_faturamento'];
$valorMedio = $_POST['f_valorMedio'];
$msg = $_POST["f_msg"];

$mensagem = "Nome: '.$nome.' <br> 
            Email: '$email.' <br> 
            Telefone: '.$telefone.' <br><br> 
            CNPJ: '.$cnpj.' <br> 
            Setor: '.$setor.' <br> 
            Faturamento: '.$faturamento.' <br> 
            Valor Medio: '.$valorMedio.' <br> 
            Mensagem: '.$msg.' <br>";

require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.****.com.br";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = 'contato@****.com.br'; 
$mail->Password = '********'; 

$mail->From = "contato@*****.com.br"; 
$mail->Sender = "contato@****.com.br"; 
$mail->FromName = "****"; 

$mail->AddAddress('contato@*****.com.br');

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Subject = "Contato Site "; 
$mail->Body = $mensagem;
$mail->AltBody = $mensagem;

$enviado = $mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();


if ($enviado) {
echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.

";
echo "Informações do erro:
" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I've tried removing the variables and adding it directly to the $mail->Body but it does not work. I don't know much PHP so I'm relying on posts here or some tutorials but I can't find the error.  :(

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing when you ask a question like this is to describe exactly *how* it's not working - we can't guess.

First of all, you're using a very old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and base your code on [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).

You're sending only plain text content, so do this:

```
$mail->isHTML(false);
$mail->Body = $mensagem;
```

You don't need to set `AltBody` when you're doing this.

If your message is arriving, but doesn't contain what you expect, do this just before calling `send()` to confirm what parameters the script received, and what you asked it to send:

```
var_dump($_POST, $mail->Body);
```

You have `SMTPDebug = 2`, so you should be seeing debug output. If you get a `false` return value from `send()`, any error should be in `$mail->ErrorInfo` - you'll see how that can be used in the example code I linked to.

If you're seeing no SMTP debug output, it means it's having trouble connecting at all, in which case you should read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) which tells you how to diagnose connection problems. The usual reasons are that your hosting provider may block outbound SMTP, or that you have outdated CA certificates.